# How to search multiple child onkeyup action in firebase using js and make the search faster?

Tags: jquery, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a customer nearly 20380 records. I am trying to perform search action using the following code

```
$('body').on('keyup','.client_txtbox',function(){
var srchTerm = $(this).val();
    var clientref = firebase.database().ref(client_root);

var escp = srchTerm+"\uf8ff";

clientref.orderByChild("client_firstname").startAt(srchTerm).endAt(escp).limitToFirst(5).once("value", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
   });
});
```

This above code is working.But I need to search multiple fields.My data looks like this
[image]

I need to search using child values like **mobile number,lastname,email**. I tried using orderByChild multiple times like this

```
clientref.orderByChild("client_firstname").startAt(srchTerm).endAt(escp).orderByChild("client_mobilenumber").startAt(srchTerm).endAt(escp).limitToFirst(5).once("value", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
   });
```

But this is not working. The first code is working but its really slow. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter by one child property. You may be able to combine the values you need, into a single property for searching properties. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: I tried this clientref.orderBy("client_firstname").startAt(srchTerm).endAt(escp).orderBy("client_lastname").startAt(srchTerm).endAt(escp); but this is not working for me. Is this code correct? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I am getting this error clientref.orderBy is not a function. I couldnot get a solution so I made this a question. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: s/`orderBy`/`orderByChild`/g